# Name for a multiplicative analogue of a Hamel basis?

Tags: hamel-basis

Let $\mathfrak B$ be a Hamel basis for $\mathbb R$ over $\mathbb Q$.  Then the set $\mathfrak{M} = \left\{ e^b | b \in \mathfrak{B} \right\}$ has the property that any  $r\in\mathbb R^+$ can be written uniquely as a product of the form
$$\prod_{v \in \mathfrak M} v^{c_v} $$
where each $c_v \in \mathbb Q$ and only finitely many values of $c_v$ are different from $0$.  Conversely, any set with this property can be obtained by exponentiating a Hamel basis -- so in a sense the two ideas are really the same thing.

Is there a name for this "multiplicative analogue" of a Hamel basis?

Comment: I doubt it has a special name.  It's just a Hamel basis for the vector space $\mathbb{R}^+$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ (with multiplication and exponentiation as the operations).

Comment: @EricWofsey that's a very good point.